# Remove elements from map with keys not containing in another vector

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

Given an stl container, say std::map:

```
std::map<int, CustomClass> some_container;
std::vector<int> real_objects;
```

How to properly efficiently remove each element from some_container map with key not in real_objects vector? Is the map best container for such a task?

Comment: You may try some implementation with [`std::remove_if()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) and an appropriate lambda.

Comment: I would say, first do a set difference between the keys of the map and the vector, then just remove what's left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first instinct is to erase chunks of non-real objects in bulk:

```
// Assuming real_objets is sorted (otherwise sort it)

auto first = some_container.begin();

for(int i : real_objects) {
  // end of the chunk to erase is the place where i could be
  // inserted without breaking the order
  auto last = some_container.lower_bound(i);

  some_container.erase(first, last);

  // if i is a key in the container, skip that element
  if(last != some_container.end() && last->first == i) {
    ++last;
  }

  first = last;
}

// and in the end, kill stuff that comes after real_objects.back()
some_container.erase(first, some_container.end());
```

This has runtime complexity O(n * log(m)), where n is `real_objects.size()` and m is `some_container.size()`, meaning it performs best if `some_container` is much larger than `real_objects`. Otherwise, since it is possible to iterate through a `std::map` in linear time, you could walk through both in lock-step and remove discrepancies in order:

```
// again, sort real_objects.
if(!some_container.empty()) { // else there's nothing to do
  auto ir  = real_objects.begin();
  auto ire = std::lower_bound(real_objects.begin(),
                              real_objects.end  (),
                              some_container.rbegin()->first);
  auto is  = some_container.begin();

  for(;;) {
    // find the next place where the real_objects and the keys of some_container don't match
    auto p = std::mismatch(ir, ire, is, [](int i, std::pair<int, int> const &p) { return i == p.first; });

    if(p.first  == real_objects  .end() ||
       p.second == some_container.end())
    {
      // upon reaching the end, remove all that comes after the
      // end of real_objects (if anything)
      some_container.erase(p.second, some_container.end());
      break;
    } else if(*p.first < p.second->first) {
      // if there's something in real_objects that's not in
      // some_container, skip it
      ++p.first;
    } else {
      // otherwise there's something in some_container that's
      // not in real_objects, so delete it.
      p.second = some_container.erase(p.second);
    }

    ir = p.first;
    is = p.second;
  }
}
```

This has runtime complexity O(max(n, m)), so it should perform well if `some_container` and `real_objects` almost match.